# How to draw dotted line between two nodes

Tags: tikz-qtree

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=60 pt}
\Tree [.I \edge node[auto=left]{M};[.II \edge node[auto=left]{L};$3,3$ \edge node[auto=right]{R};[.$x,0$ ]] 
\edge node[auto=left]{B};[.II \edge node[auto=left]{L};$0,0$ \edge node[auto=right]{R};[.$1,1$ ]]
\edge node[auto=right]{T};[.$2,2$ ] ]
\begin{scope}[dashed]
\draw (M)--(B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am trying to draw a dotted line between `M` and `B`, but don't know exactly how to identify the said nodes.

As shown above, I have used : `\draw (M)--(B)` - obviously texmaker does not recognise `(M)` and `(B)`.

Comment: `\path[draw, dashed] (M) edge (B);` ?

Comment: `\draw (M)--(B)` returns an error because no such points are defined. "M" and "B" are only node labels; they do not refer to any points in your tikzpicture. Simply add `(M)` and `(B)` before `{M}` and `{B}` in your code, respectively. Then, `\draw[dotted,thick] (M)--(B);` should produce what you want.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Do I got you right and your problem is not "how do draw a dotted line" but "how to identify/label two nodes"?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you must give a name inside `()` to the nodes in order to reference them later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=60pt}
\Tree [.I \edge node[auto=left](M){M};[.II \edge node[auto=left]{L};$3,3$ \edge node[auto=right]{R};[.$x,0$ ]] 
\edge node[auto=left](B){B};[.II \edge node[auto=left]{L};$0,0$ \edge node[auto=right]{R};[.$1,1$ ]]
\edge node[auto=right]{T};[.$2,2$ ] ]
\path[draw, densely dotted] (M) edge (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```